# Reduce code using subroutines or functions

Tags: vbscript, subroutine

I've got VBScript code for an HTA and find myself copying/pasting the code over and over.  In the below example, `CopyCheckList` looks at the dropdown list and based on the number/step, it calls the proper `Step` subroutine.  Now to avoid copying/pasting the same code 17 times, I'm hoping to get some pointers for using a Function to reduce the amount of code needed.  For an example, if Step 6 was last performed, steps 1-6 is marked DONE.

Here is my beginner copy/paste code that is functional but I'm certain that a function code drastically reduce the need for copying/pasting the code just to change one line of text.

```
Sub Copychecklist()
  Dim VMBuildStep
  VMBuildStep = document.getElementById("BuildStepChoice").Value
  If VMBuildStep = 1 Then Call Step1 Else
  If VMBuildStep = 2 Then Call Step2 Else
  If VMBuildStep = 3 Then Call Step3 Else
  If VMBuildStep = 4 Then Call Step4 Else
  If VMBuildStep = 5 Then Call Step5 Else
  If VMBuildStep = 6 Then Call Step6 Else
  If VMBuildStep = 7 Then Call Step7 Else
  If VMBuildStep = 8 Then Call Step8 Else
  If VMBuildStep = 9 Then Call Step9 Else
  If VMBuildStep = 10 Then Call Step10 Else
  If VMBuildStep = 11 Then Call Step11 Else
  If VMBuildStep = 12 Then Call Step12 Else
  If VMBuildStep = 13 Then Call Step13 Else
  If VMBuildStep = 14 Then Call Step14 Else
  If VMBuildStep = 15 Then Call Step15 Else
  If VMBuildStep = 16 Then Call Step16 Else
  If VMBuildStep = 17 Then Call Step17 End If
End Sub

Sub Step1()
  Dim sSr, sRequest, oSRSearch, sSvr, sOS, filesys, filetxt
  Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  If filesys.FileExists(filesys.GetSpecialFolder(2) & "\powershell-VM-SR-search.ps1") Then
    filesys.DeleteFile (filesys.GetSpecialFolder(2) & "\powershell-VM-SR-search.ps1")
  End If
  Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
  Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set filetxt = filesys.OpenTextFile(filesys.GetSpecialFolder(2) & "\powershell-VM-SR-search.ps1", ForAppending, True)
  sSvr = document.getElementById("TextBox1").Value
  sRequest = document.getElementByID("TextBox9").Value
  sOS = document.getElementById("TextBox10").Value
  If sRequest = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please enter something in the input form"
    Exit Sub
  End If
  filetxt.WriteLine ("Param(")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("[string]$SONum,")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("[string]$svr,")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("[string]$oschoice)")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("#Here string for VM Build procedure Note")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("$notesub = ""$svr - $oschoice""")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("$notedesc = @'")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("<pre>")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("1).   Create Record: DONE")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("2).   Request static IP Addresses: N/A")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("3).   Create the AD Server Object: ")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("4).   Create the Virtual Machine: ")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("5).   Discover the server and assign the OSD (SCCM): ")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("6).   Install the OS:")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("7).   Local Admin PW:")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("8).   Configure Virtual Disks")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("9).   Install the VMware Tools: ")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("10).  Add Hardware")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("11).  Configure NICs")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("12).  Add to SCCM  SRV-Patching  collection:")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("13).  Import Windows Firewall Policy:")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("14).  NetBackup Agent, Install/Patch and FirewallConfig")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("15).  Install Security Updates")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("16).  Update Reboot Instructions")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("17).  SCOM Maintenance Mode")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("</pre>")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("'@")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("# Create the IE com object")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("#Navigate to the Tracker IR search page.")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("$ie.navigate(" & Chr(34) & "http://WebSite.com?SONum=$SONum" & Chr(34) & ")")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("# Wait for the page to finish loading")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("do {sleep 1} until (-not ($ie.Busy))")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("$doc = $ie.document")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("$link = $doc.getElementById(""NoteSub"").Value = ""$notesub""")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("$link = $doc.getElementById(""NoteDesc"").Value = ""$notedesc""")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("$signature = @""")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("  ")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("  [DllImport(""user32.dll"")]")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("  public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);  ")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("  public static IntPtr FindWindow(string windowName){")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("      return FindWindow(null,windowName);")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("  }")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("  [DllImport(""user32.dll"")]")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("  public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd,")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("  IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X,int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("  [DllImport(""user32.dll"")]")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("  public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("  static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("  static readonly IntPtr HWND_NOTOPMOST = new IntPtr(-2);")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("  const UInt32 SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("  const UInt32 SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("  const UInt32 TOPMOST_FLAGS = SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE;")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("  public static void MakeTopMost (IntPtr fHandle)")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("  {")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("      SetWindowPos(fHandle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, TOPMOST_FLAGS);")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("  }")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("  public static void MakeNormal (IntPtr fHandle)")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("  {")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("      SetWindowPos(fHandle, HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, TOPMOST_FLAGS);")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("  }")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("""@")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("$hWnd = $ie.HWND")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("$app = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $signature -Name Win32Window -Namespace ScriptFanatic.WinAPI -ReferencedAssemblies System.Windows.Forms -Using System.Windows.Forms -PassThru")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("$null = $app::MakeTopMost($hWnd)")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("$null = $app::MakeNormal($hWnd)")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("$ie.Visible = $true")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("$button.click();")
  filetxt.WriteLine ("[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ie) | Out-Null")
  filetxt.Close
  Set oSRSearch  = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  sSr      = "powershell.exe " & filesys.GetSpecialFolder(2) & "\powershell-VM-SR-search.ps1 " & Chr(39) & sRequest & Chr(39) & " " & Chr(39) & sSvr & Chr(39) & " " & Chr(39) & sOS & Chr(39)
  oSRSearch.Run sSr, 0, true
  filesys.DeleteFile (filesys.GetSpecialFolder(2) & "\powershell-VM-SR-search.ps1")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to test this as your code requires other stuff that's not in what you posted, but anyway here's my modification to reduce it a bit:

```
Sub Copychecklist()
Dim VMBuildStep
VMBuildStep = document.getElementById("BuildStepChoice").Value
If (IsNumeric(VMBuildStep)) Then
    VMBuildStep = Int(VMBuildStep)
    If (VMBuildStep >= 1 And VMBuildStep <= 17) Then CreateFile(VMBuildStep)
End If
End Sub

Sub CreateFile(stepNumber)
Dim sSr, sRequest, oSRSearch, sSvr, sOS, filesys, filetxt, resultText(17)
BuildResultText resultText, stepNumber
Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If filesys.FileExists(filesys.GetSpecialFolder(2) & "\powershell-VM-SR-search.ps1") Then
 filesys.DeleteFile (filesys.GetSpecialFolder(2) & "\powershell-VM-SR-search.ps1")
End If
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set filetxt = filesys.OpenTextFile(filesys.GetSpecialFolder(2) & "\powershell-VM-SR-search.ps1", ForAppending, True)
sSvr = document.getElementById("TextBox1").Value
sRequest = document.getElementByID("TextBox9").Value
sOS = document.getElementById("TextBox10").Value
If sRequest = "" Then
 MsgBox "Please enter something in the input form"
 Exit Sub
End If
filetxt.WriteLine ("Param(")
filetxt.WriteLine ("[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]")
filetxt.WriteLine ("[string]$SONum,")
filetxt.WriteLine ("[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]")
filetxt.WriteLine ("[string]$svr,")
filetxt.WriteLine ("[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]")
filetxt.WriteLine ("[string]$oschoice)")
filetxt.WriteLine ("#Here string for VM Build procedure Note")
filetxt.WriteLine ("$notesub = ""$svr - $oschoice""")
filetxt.WriteLine ("$notedesc = @'")
filetxt.WriteLine ("<pre>")
filetxt.WriteLine ("1). Create Record: ") & resultText(0)
filetxt.WriteLine ("2). Request static IP Addresses: ")  & resultText(1)
filetxt.WriteLine ("3). Create the AD Server Object: ") & resultText(2)
filetxt.WriteLine ("4). Create the Virtual Machine: ") & resultText(3)
filetxt.WriteLine ("5). Discover the server and assign the OSD (SCCM): ") & resultText(4)
filetxt.WriteLine ("6). Install the OS: ") & resultText(5)
filetxt.WriteLine ("7). Local Admin PW: ") & resultText(6)
filetxt.WriteLine ("8). Configure Virtual Disks: ") & resultText(7)
filetxt.WriteLine ("9). Install the VMware Tools: ") & resultText(8)
filetxt.WriteLine ("10).    Add Hardware: ") & resultText(9)
filetxt.WriteLine ("11).    Configure NICs: ") & resultText(10)
filetxt.WriteLine ("12).    Add to SCCM  SRV-Patching  collection: ") & resultText(11)
filetxt.WriteLine ("13).    Import Windows Firewall Policy: ") & resultText(12)
filetxt.WriteLine ("14).    NetBackup Agent, Install/Patch and FirewallConfig: ") & resultText(13)
filetxt.WriteLine ("15).    Install Security Updates: ") & resultText(14)
filetxt.WriteLine ("16).    Update Reboot Instructions: ") & resultText(15)
filetxt.WriteLine ("17).    SCOM Maintenance Mode: ") & resultText(16)
filetxt.WriteLine ("</pre>")
filetxt.WriteLine ("'@")
filetxt.WriteLine ("# Create the IE com object")
filetxt.WriteLine ("$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application")
filetxt.WriteLine ("#Navigate to the Tracker IR search page.")
filetxt.WriteLine ("$ie.navigate(" & Chr(34) & "http://WebSite.com?SONum=$SONum" & Chr(34) & ")")
filetxt.WriteLine ("# Wait for the page to finish loading")
filetxt.WriteLine ("do {sleep 1} until (-not ($ie.Busy))")
filetxt.WriteLine ("$doc = $ie.document")
filetxt.WriteLine ("$link = $doc.getElementById(""NoteSub"").Value = ""$notesub""")
filetxt.WriteLine ("$link = $doc.getElementById(""NoteDesc"").Value = ""$notedesc""")
filetxt.WriteLine ("$signature = @""")
filetxt.WriteLine ("    ")
filetxt.WriteLine ("    [DllImport(""user32.dll"")]")
filetxt.WriteLine ("    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);  ")
filetxt.WriteLine ("")
filetxt.WriteLine ("    public static IntPtr FindWindow(string windowName){")
filetxt.WriteLine ("        return FindWindow(null,windowName);")
filetxt.WriteLine ("    }")
filetxt.WriteLine ("")
filetxt.WriteLine ("    [DllImport(""user32.dll"")]")
filetxt.WriteLine ("    public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd,")
filetxt.WriteLine ("    IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X,int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);")
filetxt.WriteLine ("")
filetxt.WriteLine ("    [DllImport(""user32.dll"")]")
filetxt.WriteLine ("    public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);")
filetxt.WriteLine ("")
filetxt.WriteLine ("    static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);")
filetxt.WriteLine ("    static readonly IntPtr HWND_NOTOPMOST = new IntPtr(-2);")
filetxt.WriteLine ("")
filetxt.WriteLine ("    const UInt32 SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;")
filetxt.WriteLine ("    const UInt32 SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;")
filetxt.WriteLine ("")
filetxt.WriteLine ("    const UInt32 TOPMOST_FLAGS = SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE;")
filetxt.WriteLine ("")
filetxt.WriteLine ("    public static void MakeTopMost (IntPtr fHandle)")
filetxt.WriteLine ("    {")
filetxt.WriteLine ("        SetWindowPos(fHandle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, TOPMOST_FLAGS);")
filetxt.WriteLine ("    }")
filetxt.WriteLine ("")
filetxt.WriteLine ("    public static void MakeNormal (IntPtr fHandle)")
filetxt.WriteLine ("    {")
filetxt.WriteLine ("        SetWindowPos(fHandle, HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, TOPMOST_FLAGS);")
filetxt.WriteLine ("    }")
filetxt.WriteLine ("""@")
filetxt.WriteLine ("$hWnd = $ie.HWND")
filetxt.WriteLine ("$app = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $signature -Name Win32Window -Namespace ScriptFanatic.WinAPI -ReferencedAssemblies System.Windows.Forms -Using System.Windows.Forms -PassThru")
filetxt.WriteLine ("$null = $app::MakeTopMost($hWnd)")
filetxt.WriteLine ("$null = $app::MakeNormal($hWnd)")
filetxt.WriteLine ("$ie.Visible = $true")
filetxt.WriteLine ("$button.click();")
filetxt.WriteLine ("[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ie) | Out-Null")
filetxt.Close
Set oSRSearch  = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 sSr      = "powershell.exe " & filesys.GetSpecialFolder(2) & "\powershell-VM-SR-search.ps1 " & Chr(39) & sRequest & Chr(39) & " " & Chr(39) & sSvr & Chr(39) & " " & Chr(39) & sOS & Chr(39)
 oSRSearch.Run sSr, 0, true
 filesys.DeleteFile (filesys.GetSpecialFolder(2) & "\powershell-VM-SR-search.ps1")
End Sub

Sub BuildResultText(resultText, stepNumber)
    Dim i 
    For i = 0 To UBound(resultText)
        If (i < stepNumber) Then
            resultText(i) = "DONE"
        Else
            resultText(i) = ""
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I changed the Step1 sub to be a single "overall" sub which takes a step number as argument. It creates an array for the step result text, and calls another sub to populate it with "DONE" for any step less than or equal to the step number, or nothing for any step greater than the current step (which you could of course change to be something meaningful).

So the renamed sub now just runs through its normal stuff and populates the step result text based on the array.

Finally I got rid of all those if/else statements in the first sub and replaced it with a single statement.

**Edit**

I deleted most of the code and left just enough to test the array text, and it outputs as expected - "DONE" is only outputted on the first four loops.

```
Copychecklist()

Sub Copychecklist()
Dim VMBuildStep : VMBuildStep = "4"
If (IsNumeric(VMBuildStep)) Then
    VMBuildStep = Int(VMBuildStep)
    If (VMBuildStep >= 1 And VMBuildStep <= 17) Then CreateFile(VMBuildStep)
End If
End Sub

Sub CreateFile(stepNumber)
Dim resultText(17)
BuildResultText resultText, stepNumber
Dim i
For i = 0 To UBound(resultText)
    WScript.Echo "result: " & resultText(i)
Next
End Sub

Sub BuildResultText(resultText, stepNumber)
    Dim i 
    For i = 0 To UBound(resultText)
        If (i < stepNumber) Then
            resultText(i) = "DONE"
        Else
            resultText(i) = ""
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Makes sense, however one issue appeared.  I set the build Step to 15 as a test and steps 16/17 also have DONE marked.  I tried making `If (i <= stepNumber) Then` but the same behavior occured.

Comment: Try echoing stepNumber before BuildResultText is called, and then echo i and stepNumber on each loop in the BuildResultText sub to see where it's going wrong.

Comment: Right, `BuildResultText stepNumber is 4` when set to Step 4.  Next, `i` is 0 and `stepNumber is 4`  however i counts to 17, stepNumber stays at the example step of 4.

Comment: See my edit - I tested the bit I added and it works fine for me.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but isnt `VMBuildStep = 4` hard coding the value?  Let's step back, this code goes into an HTA with 3 text boxes, a button and a dropdown list of steps (1 to 17).  Fill in the three textboxes, select the build step you left off at and click the button.  The code will open IE to the ticket and insert the checklist indicating the last step completed.  I can post the relevant HTA code if that'll help.

Comment: Aha! That's why it works for me and not for you... I fed the number as an int, but the number returned from your HTA (whatever that is... I know nothing about it) is returned as a string. If I change `VMBuildStep = 4` to `VMBuildStep = "4"` then I get the same problem as you. So the result has to be converted to an int first. I've edited the main script to do this.

Comment: Outstanding, that did the trick!  The HTA is simply a textbox for input and a drop down list showing numbers 1-17.  I'm unsure what data format `document.getElementById("TextBox1").Value` has but this update solves the problem!  -Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you're asking how you can make the `StepX` procedures so that in this part:

```
filetxt.WriteLine ("1).   Create Record: DONE")
filetxt.WriteLine ("2).   Request static IP Addresses: N/A")
filetxt.WriteLine ("3).   Create the AD Server Object: ")
filetxt.WriteLine ("4).   Create the Virtual Machine: ")
filetxt.WriteLine ("5).   Discover the server and assign the OSD (SCCM): ")
filetxt.WriteLine ("6).   Install the OS:")
filetxt.WriteLine ("7).   Local Admin PW:")
filetxt.WriteLine ("8).   Configure Virtual Disks")
filetxt.WriteLine ("9).   Install the VMware Tools: ")
filetxt.WriteLine ("10).  Add Hardware")
filetxt.WriteLine ("11).  Configure NICs")
filetxt.WriteLine ("12).  Add to SCCM  SRV-Patching  collection:")
filetxt.WriteLine ("13).  Import Windows Firewall Policy:")
filetxt.WriteLine ("14).  NetBackup Agent, Install/Patch and FirewallConfig")
filetxt.WriteLine ("15).  Install Security Updates")
filetxt.WriteLine ("16).  Update Reboot Instructions")
filetxt.WriteLine ("17).  SCOM Maintenance Mode")
```

the numbered items are marked `DONE` up to the current step number. Assuming that's the case you could do something like the following.

First create a [dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) with the action labels (in the global scope):

```
Set actions = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
actions.Add 1,  "Create Record"
actions.Add 2,  "Request static IP Addresses"
actions.Add 3,  "Create the AD Server Object"
actions.Add 4,  "Create the Virtual Machine"
actions.Add 5,  "Discover the server and assign the OSD (SCCM)"
actions.Add 6,  "Install the OS"
actions.Add 7,  "Local Admin PW"
actions.Add 8,  "Configure Virtual Disks"
actions.Add 9,  "Install the VMware Tools"
actions.Add 10, "Add Hardware"
actions.Add 11, "Configure NICs"
actions.Add 12, "Add to SCCM  SRV-Patching  collection"
actions.Add 13, "Import Windows Firewall Policy"
actions.Add 14, "NetBackup Agent, Install/Patch and FirewallConfig"
actions.Add 15, "Install Security Updates"
actions.Add 16, "Update Reboot Instructions"
actions.Add 17, "SCOM Maintenance Mode"
```

Call the procedure for building the file with `VMBuildStep` as its parameter, as [@eurotrash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30345804/1630171) has suggested in his answer:

```
If VMBuildStep >= 1 And VMBuildStep <= actions.Count Then
  CreateFile VMBuildStep
Else
  'invalid build step number, put some error handling here
End If
```

The condition is optional (you could as well just call `CreateFile VMBuildStep`), but it's a good idea to have a safety net and do error handling in case something unexpected happens.

Inside `CreateFile` build the list of the build steps like this:

```
Sub CreateFile(stepNumber)
  ...
  For i = 1 To actions.Count
    filetxt.Write Left(i & ").   ", 6) & actions(i) & ": "
    If i <= stepNumber Then filetxt.Write "DONE"
    filetxt.WriteLine
  Next
  ...
End Sub
```